# Confidential clients are not permitted to use the request body when authenticating?

Tags: access-token

I am using google oauth java client for getting the access token using authorization code. I am getting the above error not sure what's wrong. Here is the code i am using

```
    TokenResponse response = new AuthorizationCodeTokenRequest(
            new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), 
            new GenericUrl(TOKEN_END_POINT), authorizationCode
    )
    .setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI)
    .setClientAuthentication(new ClientParametersAuthentication(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET))
    .execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer after struggling a lot. Nearly it took 1 day to find the answer. Here is the solution.

```
final String encString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((clientId+":"+clientSecret).getBytes());

    TokenResponse response = new AuthorizationCodeTokenRequest(
            new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), 
            new GenericUrl(TOKEN_ENDPOINT), authorizationCode
    )
    .setRequestInitializer(new HttpRequestInitializer() {
        public void initialize(HttpRequest request) throws IOException {
            request.getHeaders().setAuthorization("Basic "+encString);
        }
    })
    .setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI)
    .execute();
```